# Can I see a printer's log about who connected to a network printer?

Tags: windows, log-files, remote-access, audit, network-printer

There's been a problem at work about a given printer that you have to connect to using a printers' server.
I don't control the server itself, but if there's a log that I can require to the server administrator, then maybe I could find out **who** added on a **given computer**, **when**, etc...
Generally I connect to the printers' server using windows explorer like \printer-server1 then select the printer right clicking it, and choosing connect,  does that leave a log on the server and/or in the host computer?
Does this log exists and records things like:
user #xx installed in computer #zz on date ### or can I find this information somewhere?
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Printers can be audited as with most other objects such as files. It needs to be enabled though on the Printer Properties > Security tab, and also at the operating system level.